# Can I assign a bool like this in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

Just a quick question,

Is the line,

```
bool myBool = (theNumber > 0);
```

valid in C#?

and obviously if 'theNumber' is larger than zero would myBool be true?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: ...all you'd have to do is flip the sign to see if it was working/valid or not

Comment: I know VisualStudio may take a long time to start, but I doubt writing this question was faster than starting up an IDE and pressing F6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick answer: There is nothing wrong with your code.

```
bool myBool = (theNumber > 0);
```

is valid and myBool will become true if theNumber is greater than zero.

Please refer to the link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx

Here the example uses:

```
bool b = true;
int days = ...;
// Assign the result of a boolean expression to b.
b = (days % 2 == 0);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Fantastic, I was just a little unsure if it was possible. Just to add. Im using Unity3D at the moment. and debugging is painful. Thats why i didn't want to just 'Try it'. Your answer was very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Quicker answer to both questions: Yes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is valid C#, provided of course that `theNumber` is a data type that can be compared to a number. The expression `theNumber > 0` evaluates to a boolean value (`true` when `theNumber` is greater than zero), and can be assigned to a boolean variable.

You don't need the parantheses around the value either, but you might want to keep them if you think that the code gets more readable:

```
bool myBool = theNumber > 0;
```